# sum text select not the value in multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, sum

I need to display the sum of the text from multiple select boxes - not the values eg.

```
<select class="summable1">
<option value="blue">1</option>
<option value="green">2</option>
<option value="black">3</option>
</select>

<select class="summable2">
<option value="orange">1</option>
<option value="pink">2</option>
<option value="purple">3</option>
</select>

<select class="summable3">
<option value="yellow">1</option>
<option value="red">2</option>
<option value="brown">3</option>
</select>

<div id="result">The sum of the selected text 1,2,3 - not the values</div>
```

Comment: OK. What's your question, problem? Post the code you tried.

Comment: like if you select 1 from first ,3 from second and 2 from third ..so you want 6 as result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var $select=$('.summable1,.summable2,.summable3');
$select.on('change',function(){
     var sum=0;
     $select.each(function(){
          sum+=parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').text(),10);
     })
     $('#result').html(sum); 
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pteupae5/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var val1 = parseInt($(".summable1").eq(0).children("option:selected").text());
var val2 = parseInt($(".summable2").eq(0).children("option:selected").text());
var val3 = parseInt($(".summable3").eq(0).children("option:selected").text());
```

You should probably create something more dynamic but you get the idea